# Twitter timeline widget disappearing on medium devices (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

When creating a website I ran into a weird error,

The Twitter Timeline Widget is auto disappearing when the device size is `medium`, I have no idea what is triggering it.

From what i have figured, this error seems to be in the AppStrap (https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/appstrap-responsive-website-template-WB0C6D0H4) not in the BootStrap itself, as i created a jSFiddle to check if it had same error, bit it was not having any.

I am using the latest release of the AppStrap theme.

The demo of problem can be found at : http://parasclasses.com

This is how the website appears
[image: Error!]

When resizing window i do not see any error log that is relevant to twitter widget in the `Mozilla Inspector`, so i can figure out the root of the problem.

Here is the log :

```
GET http://parasclasses.com/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1957ms]
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3619
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3621
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3628
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3683
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3685
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3692
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3719
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3724
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3726
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3747
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3752
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3754
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3782
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3784
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3789
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3810
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3812
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3817
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3860
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3865
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3867
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3872
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3874
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3879
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3881
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3916
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3921
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3923
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3928
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3930
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3935
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3937
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3975
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3977
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:3982
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4003
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4005
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4010
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4301
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4335
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4337
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4424
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4803
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4987
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4995
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:4997
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5004
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5006
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5016
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5032
Unknown property '-moz-background-clip'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5043
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5107
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5117
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5119
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5230
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5303
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5543
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5596
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5826
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5862
Error in parsing value for 'box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5865
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5866
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5869
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5907
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:5910
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6006
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6009
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6015
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6018
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6027
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6030
Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio'. theme-style.css:6106
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6138
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6168
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6245
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6279
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6287
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6322
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6356
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6364
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6398
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6447
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6475
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6511
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6576
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6589
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6658
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6752
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6845
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:6967
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7031
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. theme-style.css:7042
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. theme-style.css:7045
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7105
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7111
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7152
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7295
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7300
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7347
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7350
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7429
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7751
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7760
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7764
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7766
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:7865
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8260
Unknown property 'speak'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8273
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8297
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8330
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8337
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8344
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8351
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8374
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8387
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8394
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8396
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8439
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8441
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8446
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8448
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8462
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8464
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8483
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-bottomright'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8546
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8547
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8555
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8594
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8624
Error in parsing value for 'min-width'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8706
Error in parsing value for 'overflow-x'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8735
Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8756
Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. theme-style.css:8757
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8766
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8768
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8795
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8797
Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8804
Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. theme-style.css:8805
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8814
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8816
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8822
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8824
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8869
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8872
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8875
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8879
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8882
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8898
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8959
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:8962
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9133
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9137
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9140
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9206
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9211
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9282
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9284
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9319
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9334
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9348
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9367
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9402
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9620
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9698
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9734
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9738
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9741
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9754
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9859
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9863
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9866
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9879
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9885
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9900
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9958
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9963
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:9988
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10280
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10539
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10574
Error in parsing value for 'box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10577
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10578
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10581
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10619
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10622
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10716
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10719
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10725
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10728
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10737
Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme-style.css:10740
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. colour-blue.css:79
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. colour-blue.css:386
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. colour-blue.css:918
GET http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 656ms]
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery.min.js:1
GET http://parasclasses.com/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1603ms]
GET http://parasclasses.com/plugins/jPanelMenu/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 705ms]
GET http://parasclasses.com/plugins/jRespond/js/jRespond.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3097ms]
GET http://parasclasses.com/plugins/clingify/jquery.clingify.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3827ms]
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:5
Unknown property '-moz-outline'.  Declaration dropped. timeline.3fb0c4c981cd3f8f8dfb6b0ab93d6a9e.default.css:1
Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. timeline.3fb0c4c981cd3f8f8dfb6b0ab93d6a9e.default.css:1
Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. timeline.3fb0c4c981cd3f8f8dfb6b0ab93d6a9e.default.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. timeline.3fb0c4c981cd3f8f8dfb6b0ab93d6a9e.default.css:1
Expected color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. timeline.3fb0c4c981cd3f8f8dfb6b0ab93d6a9e.default.css:1
window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection. nsHeaderInfo.js:412
GET https://syndication.twitter.com/widgets/timelines/paged/529143195632795648 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 381ms]
```

Code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
        <div class="inner">
            <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/parasclasses" data-widget-id="529143195632795648">Tweets by @Html.Raw("@parasclasses")</a>
            <script>
                !function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
                    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                        js = d.createElement(s);
                        js.id = id;
                        js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }
                }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
            </script>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
        <p>Website under construction will be updated soon!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `jRespond.js` that you are using. That is the culprit that is deleting you Twitter timeline on window resize, it's some kind of conflict I suppose. Simplest option is to not use that plugin. It doesn't seem to matter if it's not loaded anyway. Open u pthe `script.js` file, jump to line 225 and edit this:

```
jQuery().themeLoadPlugin(["jPanelMenu/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js", "jRespond/js/jRespond.js"], [], initjPMenu);
```

Remove the reference to `jRespons.js`:

```
jQuery().themeLoadPlugin(["jPanelMenu/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js"], [], initjPMenu);
```

Comment: following ur solution fixed the issue, but now Menu won't expand on small devices, any suggestion for that ?

Answer (score 1):

The Jpanel Menu plugin is messing things up. It checks for the browser width and resets markup via

```
//jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js

 setupMarkup: function() {
            e("html").addClass("jPanelMenu");
            e("body > *").not(n.menu + ", " + n.options.excludedPanelContent).wrapAll('<div class="' + n.panel.replace(".", "") + '"/>');
            e(n.options.menu).clone().attr("id", n.menu.replace("#", "")).insertAfter("body > " + n.panel)
        },
 resetMarkup: function() {
            e("html").removeClass("jPanelMenu");
            e("body > " + n.panel + " > *").unwrap();
            e(n.menu).remove()
```

If you observe the elements while resizing, for smaller devices the content is wrapped in an element with class `jPanelMenu-panel`.

[image: for larger width]

[image: for smaller width]

I tried to test this in jsfiddle. I wrapped the whole content with a div on click of a button. The twitter widget disappears.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/99683kks/2/)